# How is Gorr able to heal from the Necrosword?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In the opening scene of *Thor: Love and Thunder*, Gorr slices his hand on the Necrosword as he crawls into the oasis of a god. However, his hand heals near instantaneously. How did this happen? Was it the Necrosword's magic? Does Gorr's species have powers? It's evident his daughter does.

Comment: It wouldn’t make sense to be a natural power of his otherwise he and he daughter would have healed from the starvation most likely. It is almost certainly coming from the Necrosword. Though why it could heal him before he was chosen as the next owner is a tad questionable.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - A desire to murder a god and proximity to the sword are likely sufficient to mark you out as the next owner

Comment: @Valorum he didn’t desire to kill a god on entering the oasis though. He was still worshipping him until he saw his attitude.

Comment: Hmm. I'm wondering if the godly oasis (or the proximity to his god) was the thing that was healing him

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the sword had been calling to Gorr, so presumably it already intended him as its next wielder.